# Windows Phone 8 application development on windows 10 Operating System

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-10

Is is possible to develop windows phone 8 and windows phone 7 applications in windows 10 Operating system?

If possible please provide the list of tools required.

I didn't get clear information in any sites.

Thank you so much for your support.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You just need to install the SDK.

I have Windows 10 and VS 2015. I go to Create Project -> Visual C# -> Windows -> Windows 8 and there is a option Install Windows 8/8.0/Phone tools.

Comment: As per the below link, express edition of visual studio 2015 does not support development of Windows Phone 8 application.      https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-2015-compatibility-vs.aspx

Comment: Then install Community edition. I have it and all works fine

Answer (score 1):

I've got a number of resources for you. The first is our ['Best of Build'](http://www.davevoyles.com/a-developers-guide-to-windows-10-and-the-best-of-build-mva/) content from the /BUILD tour we did this year.

This series of talks covers several of our new features, including:

- “Chromeless” window
- x:Bind
- List item
- SplitView
- AdaptiveTriggers
- Action Center/Toast notifications
- FullScreenMode
- Cortana (both WP8.1 style and the new on-canvas)

And finally, a [developer's guide to Win 10 dev](http://www.davevoyles.com/a-developers-guide-to-windows-10/). A free video cource on MVA, which covers most of what you are looking for.